# Simple Data Binding Issue

Tags: vb.net

I have developed a form for Windows VB.Net that uses a number of text boxes that are indidivually bound to separate columns in a database.  When one of the textboxes (let's call it XYZ.Text) is bound to the database, it prevents the data from any of the other bound text boxes to enter the database.  When the binding for this one text box (XYZ.Text) is removed, then all the other text boxes work fine.  Has anyone run into this before?  Is this a TableAdpater issue?  Help!

Comment: Plain VB.NET does not have any forms. You're talking about a Windows Forms form, right? If so, you should add a `winforms` tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datafield that TextXYZ is bound to and in particular any data relationships related to that field.  It may be that the other fields are dependant on the value of TextXYZ.